# UPDATE float value not posting to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a float value from a form to the database. My form is reading the data correctly and displaying if the value is already stored, but when I update nothing happens:

```
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Update') {
    foreach($_POST['game'] as $game) {
        $spread = ((floatval($game['spread']) > 0) ? $game['spread'] : 'NULL');
        $sql = "update " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule ";
        $sql .= "set spread = " . $spread . " ";
        $sql .= "where gameID = " . $game['gameID'] && "CAST('spread' AS DECIMAL(5,1)) = " . $game['spread'];
        $mysqli->query($sql) or die('Error updating score: ' . $mysqli->error);
    }
    header('Location: ./');
    exit;
}
```

And here is where I am reading the data and displaying on form:

```
    <?php
$sql = "select s.*, ht.city, ht.team, ht.displayName, vt.city, vt.team, vt.displayName ";
$sql .= "from " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule s ";
$sql .= "inner join " . DB_PREFIX . "teams ht on s.homeID = ht.teamID ";
$sql .= "inner join " . DB_PREFIX . "teams vt on s.visitorID = vt.teamID ";
$sql .= "where weekNum = " . $week . " ";
$sql .= "order by gameTimeEastern";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<table class="table table-striped">' . "\n";
    echo '  <tr><th colspan="6" align="left">Week ' . $week . '</th></tr>' . "\n";
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $homeTeam = new team($row['homeID']);
        $visitorTeam = new team($row['visitorID']);
        $rowclass = (($i % 2 == 0) ? ' class="altrow"' : '');
        echo '      <tr' . $rowclass . '>' . "\n";
        echo '          <td><input type="hidden" name="game[' . $row['gameID'] . '][gameID]" value="' . $row['gameID'] . '" />' . date('D n/j g:i a', strtotime($row['gameTimeEastern'])) . ' ET</td>' . "\n";
        echo '          <td align="right"><input type="hidden" name="gameID[' . strtolower($visitorTeam->team) . ']" value="' . $row['gameID'] . '" />' . $visitorTeam->teamName . '</td>' . "\n";
        echo '          <td><input type="text" name="game[' . $row['gameID'] . '][spread]" id="game[' . $row['gameID'] . '][spread]" value="' . $row['spread'] . '" size="3" /></td>' . "\n";
        echo '          <td align="right"><input type="hidden" name="gameID[' . strtolower($homeTeam->team) . ']" value="' . $row['gameID'] . '" />at ' . $homeTeam->teamName . '</td>' . "\n";
        echo '      </tr>' . "\n";
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</table>' . "\n";
}
$query->free;
?>
```

Any suggestions on how to get the updated values to post?

Here is the whole code as of right now:

```
    <?php
require('includes/application_top.php');
require('includes/classes/team.php');

if (!$user->is_admin) {
    header('Location: ./');
    exit;
}

if ($_POST['action'] == 'Update') {
    foreach($_POST['game'] as $game) {
        $spread = ((floatval($game['spread']) > 0) ? $game['spread'] : 'NULL');
        $sql = "update " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule ";
        $sql .= "set spread = " . $spread . " ";
        $sql .= "where gameID = " . $game['gameID'] . " && CAST('spread' AS DECIMAL(5,1)) = " . $game['spread'];
        $mysqli->query($sql) or die('Error updating spread: ' . $mysqli->error);
    }
    header('Location: ./');
    exit;
}

$week = (int)$_GET['week'];
if (empty($week)) {
    //get current week
    $week = (int)getCurrentWeek();
}

include('includes/header.php');
?>
    <h1>Enter Spreads - Week <?php echo $week; ?></h1>
<?php
//display week nav
$sql = "select distinct weekNum from " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule order by weekNum;";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$weekNav = '<div class="navbar3"><b>Go to week:</b> ';
$i = 0;
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($i > 0) $weekNav .= ' | ';
    if ($week !== (int)$row['weekNum']) {
        $weekNav .= '<a href="spreads.php?week=' . $row['weekNum'] . '">' . $row['weekNum'] . '</a>';
    } else {
        $weekNav .= $row['weekNum'];
    }
    $i++;
}
$query->free;
$weekNav .= '</div>' . "\n";
echo $weekNav;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getScores(weekNum) {
    $.get("getHtmlScores.php", {week: weekNum}, function(data) {
        for(var item in data) {
            visitorScoreField = document.getElementById('game[' + data[item].gameID + '][visitorScore]');
            homeScoreField = document.getElementById('game[' + data[item].gameID + '][homeScore]');
            OTField = document.getElementById('game[' + data[item].gameID + '][OT]');
            if (visitorScoreField.value !== data[item].visitorScore) {
                visitorScoreField.value = data[item].visitorScore;
                visitorScoreField.className="fieldLoaded";
            }
            if (homeScoreField.value !== data[item].homeScore) {
                homeScoreField.value = data[item].homeScore;
                homeScoreField.className="fieldLoaded";
            }
            if (data[item].overtime == '1') {
                OTField.checked = true;
            }
        }
    },'json');
}
</script>
<p><input type="button" value="Load Scores" onclick="return getScores(<?php echo $week; ?>);" class="btn btn-info" /></p>
<form id="spreadForm" name="spreadForm" action="spreads.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="week" value="<?php echo $week; ?>" />
<div class="table-responsive">
<?php
$sql = "select s.*, ht.city, ht.team, ht.displayName, vt.city, vt.team, vt.displayName ";
$sql .= "from " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule s ";
$sql .= "inner join " . DB_PREFIX . "teams ht on s.homeID = ht.teamID ";
$sql .= "inner join " . DB_PREFIX . "teams vt on s.visitorID = vt.teamID ";
$sql .= "where weekNum = " . $week . " ";
$sql .= "order by gameTimeEastern";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<table class="table table-striped">' . "\n";
    echo '  <tr><th colspan="6" align="left">Week ' . $week . '</th></tr>' . "\n";
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $homeTeam = new team($row['homeID']);
        $visitorTeam = new team($row['visitorID']);
        $rowclass = (($i % 2 == 0) ? ' class="altrow"' : '');
        echo '      <tr' . $rowclass . '>' . "\n";
        echo '          <td><input type="hidden" name="game[' . $row['gameID'] . '][gameID]" value="' . $row['gameID'] . '" />' . date('D n/j g:i a', strtotime($row['gameTimeEastern'])) . ' ET</td>' . "\n";
        echo '          <td align="right"><input type="hidden" name="gameID[' . strtolower($visitorTeam->team) . ']" value="' . $row['gameID'] . '" />' . $visitorTeam->teamName . '</td>' . "\n";
        echo '          <td><input type="text" name="game[' . $row['gameID'] . '][spread]" id="game[' . $row['gameID'] . '][spread]" value="' . $row['spread'] . '" size="3" /></td>' . "\n";
        echo '          <td align="right"><input type="hidden" name="gameID[' . strtolower($homeTeam->team) . ']" value="' . $row['gameID'] . '" />at ' . $homeTeam->teamName . '</td>' . "\n";
        echo '      </tr>' . "\n";
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</table>' . "\n";
}
$query->free;
?>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" />
</form>
<?php
include('includes/footer.php');
```

Comment: First of all, please read http://bobby-tables.com there about SQL injections and how to prevent them. Right now your code is really vulnerable and your database can be hacked in a few seconds. Use prepared statements. 
Also, can you pelase show us your HTML form too? I'm a bit confused from the `foreach($_POST['game'] as $game) {` ... do you have more than one field with name=game?

Comment: Change `$sql .= "where gameID = " . $game['gameID'] && "CAST(` to `$sql .= "where gameID = " . $game['gameID']." && CAST(`

Answer (score 0):

change your update query as below remove `&&` and use `and` put it in quotation

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'Update') {
  foreach($_POST['game'] as $game) {
        $spread = ((floatval($game['spread']) > 0) ? $game['spread'] : 'NULL');
        $sql = "update " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule ";
        $sql .= "set spread = " . $spread . " ";
        $sql .= "where gameID = " . $game['gameID']." AND CAST('spread' AS DECIMAL(5,1)) = " . $game['spread'];
        $mysqli->query($sql) or die('Error updating score: ' . $mysqli->error);
      }
      header('Location: ./');
      exit;
  }
```

Also use **prepared statement** to prevent from sql injection

Comment: Tried this suggestion, still not posting the updated values

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['game'] )`  and show whet you are getting

Comment: NULL comes back when I add that after form

Comment: add it after `if ($_POST['action'] == 'Update') {` and then put `die;` to stop further redirection

Comment: I can see the value in the output:

Comment: 3.5 is the value I updated, 4.5 is the existing value:

Comment: { ["gameID"]=> string(3) "254" ["spread"]=> string(3) "3.5" } [256]=> array(2) { ["gameID"]=> string(3) "256" ["spread"]=> string(3) "4.5" } } array(16) { [241]=> array(2)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a little more research and testing, the final solution that worked was making this change:

```
    $sql .= "where gameID = " . $game['gameID']." AND CAST('spread' AS DECIMAL(5,1)) = CAST('spread' AS DECIMAL(5,1))";
```